# How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage of IIS Appool in C#?

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool

Am trying to write a windows service that will be used in monitoring the memory, cpu and current requests count of IIS App Pools using C#. What I have currently (Shown below) doesn't really do this at the moment.

The code shown below correctly pools the current apps hosted in IIS, but when you try to get the performance counter of "cpu time", "memory", It raises an invalid operation exception. Looks like there is something that am missing. Any help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace ResourceMonitor.Infrastructure
{
    public class PerformanceAggregator
    {
        private static readonly List<PerformanceCounterCategory> Processes = new List<PerformanceCounterCategory>();
        private static readonly List<string> Instances = new List<string>();
        private static string _category = "Web Service";

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, List<PerformanceCounter>> Resources = new Dictionary<string, List<PerformanceCounter>>();


        private static void InitializeCounters()
        {
            if (!Instances.Any())
                return;

            foreach (var instance in Instances)
            {              

                var resources = new List<PerformanceCounter>();
                // Memory, "% Committed Bytes In Use"
                if (PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instance, _category))
                {
                    var cpuTime = new PerformanceCounter(_category, "% Processor Time", instance);
                    cpuTime.NextValue();
                    resources.Add(cpuTime);
                }

                if (PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instance, _category))
                {
                    var memory = new PerformanceCounter(_category, "% Committed Bytes In Use", instance);
                    memory.NextValue();
                    resources.Add(memory);
                }

                if (PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists(instance, @"ASP.NET"))
                {
                    var requests = new PerformanceCounter(@"ASP.NET", "requests current", instance, true);
                    requests.NextValue();
                    resources.Add(requests);
                }

                //add instances to resources dictionary
                Resources.Add(instance, resources);
            }
        }

        private static void LoadInstances()
        {
            if (!Processes.Any())
            {
                LoadPerformanceCategory(_category);
            }

            foreach (var counterCategory in Processes)
            {
                var instances = counterCategory.GetInstanceNames().ToList();
                instances = instances.Where(a => a.IndexOf("_") != 0).ToList();

                if(instances.Any())
                    Instances.AddRange(instances);
            }
        }

        private static void LoadPerformanceCategory(string category)
        {

            var categories = PerformanceCounterCategory
                .GetCategories()
                .Where(a => a.CategoryName.Contains(category))
                .ToList();

            if (categories.Any())
            {
                Processes.AddRange(categories);
            }
        }

        public static bool Load(string service)
        {
            try
            {
                _category = service;
               LoadPerformanceCategory(service);
               LoadInstances();

                //initialize counters
                InitializeCounters();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

        public static List<Resource> PoolResource()
        {
            var computedResources = new List<Resource>();
            if(Resources != null && Resources.Any())
            {
                foreach (var resource in Resources)
                {
                    var computedResource = new Resource
                    {
                        Name = resource.Key,
                        RecordedAt = DateTime.Now
                    };

                    foreach (var counter in resource.Value)
                    {
                        var value = counter.NextValue();
                        if (counter.CategoryName == "Process")
                        {
                            value = (value / Environment.ProcessorCount);
                            computedResource.CurrentCpu = value;
                        }

                        if (counter.CategoryName == "Memory")
                        {
                            value = counter.NextValue();
                            computedResource.CurrentMemory = value;
                        }

                        if (counter.CategoryName != "ASP.NET")
                            continue;

                        value = counter.NextValue();
                        computedResource.RequestCount = value;
                    }
                    computedResources.Add(computedResource);
                }
            }
            return computedResources;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only place i see you finding a value `% Processor Time` thats relevant to IIS is under the Processes category not `Web Server` as your code appears to be doing? Are you sure your looking in teh right place? If you use Processes category and filter by the executable name `w3p.exe` to get just the running app pools metrics for CPU/ram/io etc. If you have multiple app pools running, you'll see multiple copies of w3p.exe sadly. I've used the process id to get the username of the process (which is generally an app pool identify based on its name) to work out which site is which.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out how to get the % Processor Time of any process. Using WokerProcess, I get the process id, then i compute the cpu usage of that process.